# Ruby (rails) - including module in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm missing something stupid.  Help?

lib/api.rb

```
require 'httparty'

module API
  def self.call_api(query)
    base_url = "http://myapi.com"
    return HTTParty.get("#{base_url}/#{query}.json")
  end
end
```

models/job.rb

```
require 'api'

class Job
  include API

  def self.all(page=1)
    self.call_api "jobs?page=#{page}"
  end

end
```

> Job::all
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `call_api' for Job:Class

If I move my "call_api" directly into the Job class, it works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other answers have pointed out your issue you should have extend instead of include:

```
class Job
  extend API
```

You might also like to consider using the following pattern which aside from being useful can also help to alleviate the confusion, since you can tell straight away that your class methods are in the `ClassMethods` module while your instance methods are directly in the `MyModule` module.

```
module MyModule

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods 
    def my_class_method
    end
  end

  def my_instance_method
  end
end
```

This uses Ruby's `included` callback (which is fired every time a module in included in a class), we redefine the callback (which normally doesn't do anything), to extend the class in which the module was included with the `ClassMethods` sub module. This is a very common metaprogramming pattern in Ruby. If you use this pattern you no longer have to worry about extend, just use `include`:

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule
```

then:

```
MyClass.my_class_method
MyClass.new.my_instance_method
```

You can also take this pattern a little bit further:

```
module MyModule
  include ClassMethods

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods 
    def my_class_method
    end
  end

  def my_instance_method
  end
end
```

Notice that the parent module includes its child `ClassMethods` module directly. This way  `my_class_method` becomes both an instance and a class method:

```
class MyClass
  include MyModule

MyClass.my_class_method
MyClass.new.my_class_method
```

You have to be a bit careful if you do that about how you code your method in the `ClassMethods` child module. But I have found this pattern extremely handy on occasion.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you need is to define `call_api` as an instance method in your module, then `extend API` instead of `include API`. In general, [include is for instance methods and extend is for class methods](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining the method `call_api` directly on the `API` module, rather than on the inheritance chain of the `Job` class.

You can call `API.call_api` just fine, but the problem is that API's "instance methods" are not part of the inheritance chain (not instance methods defined for the receiver of the included module, but API's singleton instance methods - remember `API` is an instance of the class Module with its own methods)

This is way of doing what you are trying to do:

```
module API
  def self.included(base)
    def base.call_api(...)
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

but there may be cleaner ways using `extend` rather than `include` on your classes.